# IntegrityError when try to insert image to text

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm just trying to insert picture in django-cms wysiwyg editor, but:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/cms/page/3/edit-plugin/3/edit-plugin/15/
(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my-table`.`cmsplugin_filerimage`, CONSTRAINT `cmsplugin_ptr_id_refs_id_c078c386` FOREIGN KEY (`cmsplugin_ptr_id`) REFERENCES `cms_cmsplugin` (`id`))')
```

The same thing happens when I try to use django-cms own picture plugin.

Comment: I had a similar problem, sometimes that problem happens because some tables you have got them in `InnoDB` and others in `MyISAM`

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to change type of tables so I just removed them and now i don't understand why they're not created when i do `migrate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see there is no way to mark comment as an answer so I'll just thank Victor for his comment. In my case the type of cmsplugin_filer tables was InnoDB while other tables' engine was MyISAM. So I just changed type of engine for filer's tables to MyISAM:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ENGINE=MyISAM
```